# Linux: Send email to another address instead of /var/spool/mail/root

Tags: linux, email, root

I manage a micro linux server on Amazon EC2.  Occasionally I get email sent to the root account and if I'm logged in, I'll get the notice:

```
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

**How do I get these emails sent to another email address (like user@gmail.com) instead?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed s/^root.*/root:\ someuser@gmail.com/ -i /etc/aliases && newaliases
```

Run as root. Will alias the delivery address for root to the email address of your choice.
Otherwise, manually edit */etc/aliases* and modify the root's alias in the form of:
root: someuser@some.mail.host
to have root's e-mails automatically forwarded to that address.
For more information on the */etc/aliases* file, **man aliases**

Comment: And you need an MTA which is able to send mail to "the outside world". This does not work with only a MDA.

Comment: @mailq: Please elaborate

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this has the effect of setting the line root: someuser@gmail.com in the /etc/aliases file and then running 'newaliases'.

Comment: @Dan That is correct. \@OG: One should be nice provide clear instructions rather than shell golf scripts.

Comment: On a stripped down server one could have only a [MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent) which can only deliver to local mailboxes. Or a "real" [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) which acts as SMTP client, SMTP server, MDA and maybe even more.

Comment: @Jeff: thanks for the comment, I've edited the answer. The previous one was posted in a bit of a rush but required very basic regexp knowledge to figure out and Dan managed to figure it out correctly, so no 'macchiavellic' intention was meant.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between having your mail address in .forward and in /etc/aliases is that, if you use .forward, the mail will first land in your local mailbox (possibly /var/spool/mail/root by default) and then a copy will get forwarded to you. In the /etc/aliases way, however, it will get sent directly to you, without any local delivery. You might want to consider this while choosing the method, whether you want a local copy to remain on server or not.

Comment: This is of course valid in case you have a proper MTA, otherwise, the other answers are more relevant as /etc/aliasas wont work for remote delivery.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is for forward root's mail.

`echo "youraddress@domain.com" > /root/.forward`

You'll need to make sure that sendmail/postfix is installed and running and that your host can connect to the SMTP servers for the receiving domain.  Otherwise, you'll need to configure some host as a "smart host" to relay all of your mail.

To get the SMTP servers:
`nslookup -type=mx domain.com`

To test connectivity:
`telnet <hostname> 25` or `nc -z <hostname> 25`